# Finding distribution function

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ denote iid random variables such that $X_1$ is continuously distributed with density $p(x)$ and distribution function $F(x)$ where $F(0) = 0, F(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$, and $p(0) > 0$. Let

$\hspace{15mm}Y = n\cdot  \min \{X_1,...,X_n\}$.

Then there exists a random variable Y such that:

$\hspace{15mm} Y_n \xrightarrow{D}Y$ as $n \xrightarrow{} \infty$.

What is the distribution function of $Y$?

I'm not sure how to proceed with this question. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for $t\geqslant 0$,
$$\mathbb P\{Y_n\leqslant t\}=\mathbb P\{\min_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n} X_j\leqslant t/n\}=1-\mathbb P\{\min_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n} X_j>t/n\}=
1-\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\{X_j\gt t/n\}\right).$$
Using the fact that $(X_j)$ is iid, we get 
$$\mathbb P\{Y_n\leqslant t\}=1-(1-F(t/n))^n.$$
Now, we have to use the fact that $X_1$ has a density in order to compute the limit.